# Mosquitto - EMQX bridge connection name

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto, emq

1) How to determine the Mosquitto bridge connection name.

The snippet written below is from the EMQx documentation (http://emqtt.io/docs/v2/bridge.html#mosquitto-conf)

```
connection emqttd
address 127.0.0.1:2883
topic sensor/# out 2
```

the connection name - emqttd is written on what basis?

2) I have a tcp connection open from EMQX on the host 172.22.25.53 and port 2883. 
When i try connecting from the same system. It works absolutely fine. But from a different system, I get this error

```
C:\Program Files\mosquitto>mosquitto.exe -c mosquitto.conf -v
1542182003: mosquitto version 1.5.3 starting
1542182003: Config loaded from mosquitto.conf.
1542182003: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1542182003: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1542182003: Bridge local.AOI146.emq@172.22.25.53 doing local SUBSCRIBE on topic BA/#
1542182003: Connecting bridge emq@172.22.25.53 (172.22.25.53:2883)
1542182003: Bridge AOI146.emq@172.22.25.53 sending CONNECT
1542182003: Error creating bridge: Unknown error.
1542182003: Warning: Unable to connect to bridge emq@172.22.25.53.
```

My mosquitto.conf file is:

```
connection emqx
address 172.22.25.53:2883
cleansession false
topic AB/# both 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The connection name is the value after `connection` in the configuration file. As described in the bridge section of the mosquitto.conf man [page](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html#idm633)

e.g.

```
connection foo
```

Will result in a connection name of `foo`.

`172.22.25.53` is in the reserved range 172.16.0.0 – 172.31.255.255, I'm going to guess you are running emq in a docker container and you are trying to access the container using it's Docker internal IP address. You will need to expose the port on your host machine to be able to access it from a remote machine.

Comment: Nope. I haven't used docker. 172 is an internal set of IP Address. These systems are corporate connection. So these ports are already exposed via LAN. Not sure how else to expose the ports. 
My bridge connection gets connected very rarely. Its not stable.

Comment: And also, So since the connection name is foo, i dont need to mention it anywhere else on my broker on the other end right?